Selenium node.js - Setting cookies for auto redirected page
I'm testing an app on localhost:4200. For authentication, the page redirects me to an external login page the first time, then uses cookies after that. I'm trying selenium to automate my testing. To avoid having to log in, I want to get the localhost page with the cookies I exported from firefox. But I'm getting errors due to the redirection.
await driver.get('http://localhost:4200');

for (let cookie of cookies) {
  await driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
}

Error:
InvalidCookieDomainError: Cookies may only be set for the current domain (<login url>)
Adding driver.sleep before and after the cookie setting doesn't help
I tried adding cookies before get and got InvalidCookieDomainError: Document is cookie-averse
Example cookie:
  {
      "name": "access_token",
      "value": "cookievalue",
      "domain": "localhost",
      "hostOnly": true,
      "path": "/",
      "secure": false,
      "httpOnly": false,
      "sameSite": "no_restriction",
      "session": true,
      "firstPartyDomain": "",
      "partitionKey": null,
      "storeId": "firefox-default",
      "id": 5
  }

